# NSInternalInconsistencyException: Invalid update in tableView with sections when i delete the row and then update the table

Tags: uitableview

This the method where i am updating and animating the tableview after delete the data from the section 1 and when i am trying to update that time application is crahed -

(void)onBusinessSuccess:(id)dataObj {

if([_isBuisnessCall isEqualToString: IS_LABORDER])
{

```
BusinessSingleton *currentBusinessSingleton = [BusinessSingleton sharedInstance];
[[currentBusinessSingleton arrVirtualNetworkCall] removeObjectAtIndex:[currentBusinessSingleton containsObjectAtIndex:[self objLabOrderBusiness]]];

if(!_reloading){
    self.objLabTestVO = (LabTestVO*)dataObj;
    //adding the new rows
    __block NSMutableArray *insertArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    [arrNewLabTestDataSource enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [insertArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
    }];

    __block NSMutableArray *insertArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    [self.objLabTestVO.arrUnsignLab enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [insertArray1 addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:1]];
    }];

    __block NSMutableArray *insertArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    [self.objLabTestVO.arrSignLab enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [insertArray2 addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:2]];
    }];

    [tableViewLeft beginUpdates];
    [tableViewLeft insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [tableViewLeft insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertArray1 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [tableViewLeft insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertArray2 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [tableViewLeft endUpdates];
    [tableViewLeft setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1,0,0,0)];
    [tableViewLeft setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just add bool variable and check if condition

if(!_reloading && !_isrecallbuiness ){

self.objLabTestVO = (LabTestVO*)dataObj;
    //adding the new rows
    __block NSMutableArray *insertArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    [arrNewLabTestDataSource enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [insertArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
    }];

```
__block NSMutableArray *insertArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
[self.objLabTestVO.arrUnsignLab enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [insertArray1 addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:1]];
}];

__block NSMutableArray *insertArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
[self.objLabTestVO.arrSignLab enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [insertArray2 addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:2]];
}];

[tableViewLeft beginUpdates];
[tableViewLeft insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableViewLeft insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertArray1 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableViewLeft insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertArray2 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableViewLeft endUpdates];
[tableViewLeft setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1,0,0,0)];
[tableViewLeft setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)];
```

}